What are some resources to get started in quantum computing for nuclear and high-energy physics?
One of the big hopes for quantum computing is to simulate quantum many-body systems with quantum systems and thereby solve many outstanding problems that are otherwise intractable in nuclear and high-energy physics. Many classically intractable problems in nuclear and high-energy physics are named in articles that are easily found online by searching either "quantum computing for nuclear and high-energy physics." However, I can't find any beginner-friendly resources to learn how to apply quantum computing to any of these problems. I know the rudimentary basics of quantum computing from the YouTube series Understanding Quantum Information and Computation by John Watrous. My question is, are there any resources to break into quantum computing for nuclear and high-energy physics students and researchers? Any advice/tips would be helpful!

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1367/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2082/55, and the many links therein
