# Getting started with quantum computing from a computer science perspective

Tags: resource-request

I started this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107002176) on quantum computing (Nielsen and Chuang). I have gone through the first chapter but I need to really understand the concepts; what should I do? Should I cover some background topics or move to some other book. By the way, I have done Bachelors in Computer Science; I never studied quantum before but I started this book so I can start research on quantum algorithms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a study guide exist that starts from a "purely CS background" and advances towards "making a new quantum programming language"?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/does-a-study-guide-exist-that-starts-from-a-purely-cs-background-and-advances) and [Are there any organised resources available from where I can begin my quantum computing studies?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/are-there-any-organised-resources-available-from-where-i-can-begin-my-quantum-co?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the resources mentioned in the [Linked](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6526) threads, I recently came across a textbook that's very much like an "undergraduate version" of Nielsen and Chuang, and should be helpful for you to get started.

[Elements of Quantum Computation and Quantum Communication - Anirban Pathak](https://www.crcpress.com/Elements-of-Quantum-Computation-and-Quantum-Communication/Pathak/p/book/9781466517912)

> #### Preface:
>
> This introductory textbook is written primarily for **undergraduate students of physics, mathematics, computer science and other related disciplines**. It is also expected to be valuable to teachers as well as to researchers working in other domains, who are interested in obtaining an understanding of quantum computation and quantum communication. I used to offer a course on quantum information theory from 2002-2006. Later I offered a few short courses in different summer schools and workshops. This book is prepared mainly from those lectures. There are many excellent textbooks
> on quantum information theory. However, most of those books are either
> too technical for beginners or they are not complete. This was one of my
> reasons for writing this book. But more importantly, every teacher has
> his/her own way to present the subject and teachers are usually biased on
> that. I belong to that class of biased teachers and this book is an initiative to present the subject in my way. Another fact that played a very important role in the present initiative is that there are engineering students who hardly know anything about quantum mechanics and there are physics students who do not know what a Turing machine is. But students from both groups are equally interested in quantum computing and often they join
> the same course. Keeping both kinds of students in mind, this book aims
> to give a brief idea of quantum computation and quantum communication
> in a self-contained manner. It does not demand any prior knowledge of
> quantum mechanics or computer science.(...)