# Resources in Spanish to start learning quantum computing and quantum programming (Qiskit)

Tags: programming, qiskit, resource-request

I’m starting an engineering degree in computer systems and I’m starting to get really interested in quantum computing. First of all, I don’t know where or how to start and I would really like to learn about this. Second and last I think I have a good level of English but I would really like to give all this information and manuals to my friends and professors so it surely would be awesome to have information in Spanish too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programming quantum computers for non-physics majors](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/programming-quantum-computers-for-non-physics-majors)

Comment: I'm not convinced that a question asking for a resource in Spanish is a duplicate of a question asking for an equivalent resource in English... (of course, the English part is already answered, but that's not the entire question)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the resources on [this page](https://community.qiskit.org/education/#textbook) especially the textbook as that starts from the very fundamentals and works up. There are also [tutorials](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/tree/master/qiskit) to teach you about the basics of quantum computing and work up to very complex topics.

As for resources in Spanish, if you join the qiskit [Slack community](https://join.slack.com/t/qiskit/shared_invite/enQtNjQ5OTc5ODM1ODYyLTc2YWJhOWViZDA2OWI5N2EyMjIxN2YwODM5MWQyN2Q3MjczOGRlMDU4MzMxMWE5MzZjMzEzYzM3MmJiMzU5MzU) there is a channel #spain where they discuss quantum computing in Spanish.