How to learn about quantum computing and qiskit
I am an undergraduate in Electrical engineering, I have taken one course on quantum mechanics but nothing related to quantum information or algorithms or quantum computing. I looked up some courses and tutorials online but many of them are too mathematically intensive. I am interested in pursuing a career in quantum computing (especially superconducting qubits), and for this I would like to know how and where should I start.
I also wanted to learn qiskit, which is a software-development-kit for quantum computers. I looked on their github but it seems too overwhelming and I am confused how should I start. I also followed some stack exchange answers but the links in those answers are boken or lead to non-existant pages.

possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1367/55

Happy to move my answer to the other question, if it is decided to be the place for this discussion. I can see the rationale behind it. However, SO does not have a "please give me up to date resources" button on these older questions.

Being a PhD student in the field of quantum computing, here is how I started learning about quantum computing and qiskit.
First, as you have already studied the basics of quantum mechanics, I would suggest you start learning about the basics of quantum information and quantum circuits. Then after this go through the next chapter on quantum algorithms. After this I suggest you to take the practice tests at the end of these chapters to solidify the foundations of what you learnt.
Now, coming to the second part of your question about how to start with qiskit. I started learning about qiskit from the online documentation found here. I would recommend you to start going through the section step-by-step, which means you start from the section called "Start" and then move on to next section "Build" followed by "Transpile", "Verify", and "Run". These sections describe in great detail all the ways on how you can write a code in qiskit and how you can transpile the code to match the attributes of the real quantum system that you want to run your code on. If you prefer, you can look at all the tutorials on various topics found here.
Another good source to learn qiskit is their youtube channel and blog. On youtube, I would especially recommend the new series "Coding with Qiskit 1.x" which quickly goes through how to install and run qiskit code in the latest version qiskit 1.x.
When learning qiskit, if you need an even more detailed help with the function and classes in qiskit then you can look here in the API reference for qiskit, qiskit-ibm-runtime, and qiskit-ibm-runtime REST API.
An important note: Do not mix qiskit version<=0.46 with qiskit version 1.x. The online documentation is very descriptive about how to upgrade to qiskit 1.x versions, so follow those instructions.

I believe https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/ is a wonderful starting point for Qiskit and Quantum Information. I also recommend https://quantum.country/ which is more about the theory than the coding side.
